# Next.js build does not use .env.development

Tags: build, next.js

I would like to set up two different builds for a next.js application.

package.json:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "debug": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
  "build:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && next build",
  "build:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && next build",
  "start": "node server.js"
},
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "next": "^10.0.0",
  "react": "17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "17.0.1",
  "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.3",
  "sass": "^1.32.11"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
}
...
```

Then I created `.env.development` and `.env.production` with different hostname and port, like this:

```env
HOST=127.0.0.3
PORT=9999
API_DOMAIN=http://$HOST:$PORT/API
```

But if I run `npm run build:dev` it displays this:

```
$ npm run build:dev

> learn-starter@0.1.0 build:dev
> set NODE_ENV=development && next build

warn  - You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment. This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised against. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env
info  - Loaded env from W:\web\projects\xfb\xfbweb\react\.env.production
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option not enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
FetchError: request to http://127.0.0.3:9999/API/GET/blog/?mode_cd=summary&offset=1&limit=2&language_cd=eng failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.3:9999
...
```

It seems this uses the `.env.production`. How can I force this to use the `.env.development` in this case?
By the way, if i run `npm run build:prod` it also uses the `.env.production`.
I tried to update next to v12.1.0 but still do the same.

Comment: Running into exactly the same, did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

We use Docker containers so for the development we had to copy the file `.env.development` to `.env.production` before `npm run build` command in dockerfile. That is the only way we could solve this problem.

Comment: This solution is fine, I just hate that it's currently the best option. How has this been an issue for so long?